# Send a client certificate with WebBrowserControl

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have an application that will need to host a web page (from a 3rd party) in the WebBrowser Control.

In order to access the web app, I will need to dynamically add a client certificate.  I need to implement something like the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2066735/67038 but with a WebBrowser control (that example uses System.Net.WebClient)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: The project was cancelled, so we never went to production with anything.  I think that the last thing that we were looking at was to install the cert with a setup, instead of trying to do so dynamically.