# Get request to a url throws exception using Webclient but works fine if open it in browser

Tags: c#, webclient

I have very strange issue. I am trying to make a get request to a url using WebClient

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.DownloadString("https://api.test.kount.net/rpc/v1/orders/detail.xml");
```

It throws following exception.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: The decryption operation failed, see inner exception. ---> 

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The message received was unexpected or badly formatted --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessReadErrorCode(SecurityStatus errorCode, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, 

Byte[] extraBuffer) at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
```

But if I open this url in browser, it opens and return a xml response. What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding a client certificate like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066489/how-can-you-add-a-certificate-to-webclient-c

Comment: Just use a different browser (other than the one you logged in previously ), and you'll get 401-Unauthorized.

Comment: @EZI I tried other browsers too, I get this xml response <response>
<status>failure</status>
<count>
<success>0</success>
<failure>1</failure>
</count>
<errors>
<error>
<code>401</code>
<message>Authentication Failure</message>
<scope/>
</error>
<error>
<code>404</code>
<message>Missing or invalid input</message>
<scope/>
</error>
</errors>
<result/>
</response>

Comment: Yes, it returns an error (401) and the xml you posted. So what?

Comment: It doesn't return this xml from c# codes, it throws web exception.

Comment: @sanjeev is your question: "how can I get this error message" ?

Comment: Right. I want to get this error message.

Comment: @sanjeev see my answer below....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Right. I want to get this error message.

Catch the exception and read the content.

```
var responseStr = "";
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    responseStr = client.DownloadString("https://api.test.kount.net/rpc/v1/orders/detail.xml");
}catch(WebException wex)
{
    responseStr = new StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

One more alternative

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://api.test.kount.net/rpc/v1/orders/detail.xml");
var status = resp.StatusCode;
responseStr =  await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

All of them works...

Comment: @sanjeev I tested it again. it returns that xml.

Comment: FYI: if I access this url using curl command, it returns me valid xml response. Issue is only when I access it via c# codes.

Comment: @sanjeev FYI: I get  this error messages in many different ways ( in c#). all works.

Comment: Very strange. Believe me wex.Response is null for my case. Any ideas why?

Comment: I asked my client to test my codes from their machine and it worked. I don't the reason why it doesn't work from my machine. Thanks for your help. I'll mark it as answer.