# How to fix "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." when trying to download osu! avatar

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, avatar

I want to download osu! avatars to use them, but keep getting this error:

> The SSL connection could not be established.

Inner exception is:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Получено непредвиденное сообщение или оно имеет неправильный формат

Example url: 
https://a.ppy.sh/10638551?1524507784.png

I tried using HttpClient and WebClient but without any success.

```
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     var resp = await client.GetAsync("https://a.ppy.sh/10638551?1547998515.jpeg");
     var responseStr = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     File.WriteAllText("html/avatars/avatar.jpeg", responseStr);
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.  We can't help you without it.

Comment: Ok. So it told you to look at the Inner Exception. What is it? Also, as Amy stated, you need to supply code when asking a question about non-working code. Please [Edit] your question and include only the relevant code, and the Inner Exception.

Comment: Well the inner exception is in Russian and translates to "Unexpected message received or incorrect format"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629206/get-request-to-a-url-throws-exception-using-webclient-but-works-fine-if-open-it

Comment: Sadly i still encounter the same error. I edited my code to match the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629206/get-request-to-a-url-throws-exception-using-webclient-but-works-fine-if-open-it.

Comment: Well if you follow the answer, you'll realize its telling you how to read the content of the stream so you can know what the cause of the error is.  The answer *doesn't fix* the error.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?  This looks like the SSL connection cannot be established, and thus might be a cipher issue.  Ensure your HttpClient supports an appropriate version of SSL.  Also, off topic, but typically you wouldn't read a JPEG (or any binary data) as a string.

Comment: The error states:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: .net Core if i remember correctly. As for "why": i'm making a discord bot and want to integrate osu! statistics via html image, but ImageGenerator cant view this url.

Comment: How do you know this URL is valid and is meant to be accessed directly like this?

Comment: It's the only url that contains the avatar. Even the official osu! site refers to this link. Also, if you just use this link in html it works, but i use a lib that converts html to image and sadly this lib can't get the image in the url, so i'm trying to download the avatar and use it localy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Answer:

---

After some time i figured that the library i was using was a bit bad. And after that i discovered [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

With that in mind i started using Selenium WebDriver and figured that i can take a screenshot of a page i needed, then i cropped that image and i got what i needed.
So theres no need to continue this issue.

Comment: Using this way not fix the problem.

Comment: Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/535932/xamarin-android-throws-error-ssl-routinesopenssl-i.html)

Answer (score 6):

I found te solution this blog helped me

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
{
    // local dev, just approve all certs
    if (development) return true;
    return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None ;
};
```

https://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/validate-ssl-certificate-with-servicepointmanager

Comment: careful, this sort of code leaks into production before you know it

Comment: This solution works with HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse and WebClient, not only with HttpClient. 
Just leave the return true and remove everything else.
Kudos!

Comment: Do not use in production, it enables man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Before use HttpClient you should setup HttpClientHandler;

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += 
                (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
                {
                    return true;
                };
```

only than your HttpClient code.
Must Work for .net Core 3.*

Comment: ack - be careful.  there is a reason x590 certificates are used.

Comment: Did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I believe we may have solved this exact issue (or one very similar)

In our case we got the same exception, but strangely from only a single machine.

After some investigation, we used this software (https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download) to determine that there were **no shared cipher suites between our box and the one we were attempting to contact**.

We used the software to enable a supported suite on our box and rebooted.

Once back up and running, everything worked fine.

Ultimately this was a machine configuration issue and not a coding one.

**[Note: I have no affiliation with this software or it's company, and I'm sure other methods could be used to achieve this, but I know this worked one for us]**

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar Issue, now can able to populate schema and rebuild index.
Note: Make sure IIS is Stopped and all Solr services in services stopped. <services.msc>

steps 1: Did switch to Linux container in docker and switched back to previous. step 2: Executed down.ps1 and below list in Windows Powershell in Admin Mode

```
Stop-Service docker
Stop-service hns
Start-service hns
Start-Service docker
docker network prune
```

step 3: then Execute docker/clean.ps1
step 4: Execute \init.ps1
step 5: Execute docker-compose up -d
and up.ps1.

Not sure the flow consideration on actual steps but it started populating and building index for my setup.