# "The SSL connection could not be estabiished", Xamarin Android app on Android device not emulator

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, certificate

Testing my Xamarin cross-platform app on an Android Device, I have the following message when I try to make an HTTP request: "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER at /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.c:217" and "SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER"

Testing the app on Android Emulator it works fine, but in phisically device I have this error. I read that is a problem with server certificates, but how can I solve it?

Best Regards :)

Comment: is the url you're requesting actually HTTPS?  Have you checked the server SSL config - there are many online tools that will check the validity of your configuration

Comment: Yes, I'm requesting HTTPS. I've tried online tools but I'can't see if my configuration is valid. Unfortunately, I'm a beginner on server and certificates :(

Comment: There are many workarounds to this issue , did them help ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54297514/how-to-fix-the-ssl-connection-could-not-be-established-see-inner-exception-w ,https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573356/xamarin-android-ssl-error-connecting-to-signalr.html